# R extracting rows with different values from matrices

Tags: r, matrix, comparison, extract

I have two matrices m1 and m2 having the same structure, now I need to create 2 new matrices
1) the first one (called Partenza) having from m1 all the rows which are different from m2
2) the second one (calle Arrivo) having from m2 the same rows

```
m1 
    row_num  datoA        datoB
    1          p           f
    3          h           b
    5          c           m
    6          c           r
    9          m           f
    14         a           b

m2 
    row_num  datoA        datoB
    1          p           f
    3          h           b
    5          c           g
    6          a           r
    9          m           f
    14         x           j
```

My result should be:

```
Partenza (taken from m1)
    row_num  datoA        datoB
    5          c           m
    6          c           r
    14         a           b

Arrivo (taken from m2)
    row_num  datoA        datoB
    5          c           g
    6          a           r
    14         x           j
```

I tried

```
zzz <- setdiff(m1,m2)  
partenza<-m1[m1[,"ROW_NUM"] %in% zzz,]
arrivo<-  m1[m1[,"ROW_NUM"] %in% zzz,]
```

But it doesn't work telling me that zzz is alway empty (and i am sure it should be not!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base` R (no package needed), you can do:

```
diffrow<-sapply(1:nrow(m1),function(x) !all(m1[x,]==m2[x,]))
partenza<-m1[diffrow,]
arrivo<-m2[diffrow,]
```

Another option, using the `setdiff` function from package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
partenza<-setdiff(m1,m2)
arrivo<-setdiff(m2,m1)
```

*In both cases, you'll get:*

```
> partenza
#  row_num datoA datoB
#3       5     c     m
#4       6     c     r
#6      14     a     b
> arrivo
#  row_num datoA datoB
#3       5     c     g
#4       6     a     r
#6      14     x     j
```

**data:**

```
m1<-structure(list(row_num = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 14L), datoA = c("p", 
"h", "c", "c", "m", "a"), datoB = c("f", "b", "m", "r", "f", 
"b")), .Names = c("row_num", "datoA", "datoB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
m2<-structure(list(row_num = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 14L), datoA = c("p", 
"h", "c", "a", "m", "x"), datoB = c("f", "b", "g", "r", "f", 
"j")), .Names = c("row_num", "datoA", "datoB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use other packages, I am allowed to use only Igraph and standard R library

Comment: @AlexFort, then you can go with my `base` R solution (no package needed)

Comment: CathG this is what I did and it worked smooth and nice,  thanks

Comment: @AlexFort, and I'll do my best to help but, as I'm not used to graphs, I'm not sure I'll be the one answering your new question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `anti_join` function from the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
package(dplyr)

m1 <- data.frame(
  row_num = c(1,3,5,6,9,14),
  datoA = c("p","h","c","c","m","a"),
  datoB = c("f","b","m","r","f","b")
  )

m2 <- data.frame(
  row_num = c(1,3,5,6,9,14),
  datoA = c("p","h","c","a","m","x"),
  datoB = c("f","b","g","r","f","j")
)

Partenza <- anti_join(m1,m2) %>% arrange(row_num)
Arrivo <- anti_join(m2,m1) %>% arrange(row_num)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use other packages, I am allowed to use only Igraph and standard R library